# How does a state change in time for a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I was reading my textbook and there was this question: For the fundamental state of an infinite square well:
$$ \left| \psi \right \rangle = \sqrt {\frac{2}{L}} \sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)$$
if the potential $V$ changes to $0$ suddenly, how would the state change in time?
I imagine a wave packet becoming wider moving to the right (like a gaussian wave packet). Is it correct and why?

Comment: These problems always start with decomposing the initial state into energy eigenstates. The latter are $e^{ikx}$ in this case.

Comment: Your wave function at the initial time $t=0$ is $\psi(0,x)= \sqrt{2/L} \sin(\pi x/L) \Theta(x) \Theta(L-x)$ and you want to know the wave function $\psi(t,x)$ at a later time $t$ when the particle moves freely (no potential). Do you know the integral kernel for $\psi(t,x) =\int dx^\prime K(t-0;x-x^\prime) \psi(0,x^\prime)$? What did you try? It is plausible that the wave packet will spread out in space. But why should it move to the right? The expectation value of the momentum in your initial state vanishes. Why should this change with time in the case of  free motion?

Comment: Is there a way to predict approximately how it changes in time without doing any calculations? I wish to draw an approximate form of it at a later time (if it spreads out, if it moves, etc.)

Comment: Use the Heisenberg picture. There you can see it with a minimum of calculational effort.